# Anythingslider jwplayer and WordPress loop?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, jwplayer, anythingslider

I'm using anythingslider in WordPress and jwplayer. I have a custom field in my custom post types which stores either a video URL or embed code.

This is the loop I use which is displaying the video URL or embed code from the custom field in the slider

```
<ul id="slider">
<?php $the_slider = new WP_Query('post_type=product'); while($the_slider->have_posts()) : $the_slider->the_post(); ?>

    <?php //if(has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <li>
    <?php if(   get_field('video_preview'))
    {
        echo get_field('video_preview');
    }?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

I need to some how wrap the get_field into the javascript for jwplayer which would look like the below. I tried a few ways but I think the javascript is getting looped also and not working. How can I create a loop to use the js below with the above code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.example.com/video.mp4",
    width: "100%",
    height: "315px"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the JW Player always loop your content, you just need to change this piece of code:

```
height: "315px"
```

To this:

```
height: "315px",
repeat: "true"
```

I am assuming you are using JW6. If you are not using JW6, the "repeat" option would be "always" instead of "true"

Hope this helps!